# How to make default environment as conda environment in Spyder

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, spyder, conda

I have installed tensorflow in conda environment and managed to connect it to jupyter by installing nb_conda and its working. But in Spyder it still shows "tensorflow module name not found" (perhaps Spyder is not connected to the conda environment). I have two questions :

```
1. How to enable Spyder to connect with conda environment so that I can run tensorflow

2. How to change default environment from "root" in conda prompt to my own created environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

Spyder runs in the conda enviroment in which it is installed. With Anaconda install, you get it installed in the base interpreter.

1. For TensorFlow, create a new conda enviroment.
2. Install tensorflow in it.

   conda install tensorflow
3. Install Spyder in the same enviroment.

   conda install spyder

Or, directly install tensorflow in the base interpreter. Open the Anaconda prompt and enter ,

```
( base ) $ conda install tensorflow
```